# Chrome Selenium WebDriver failing with timeouts

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a windows service that periodically runs through a bunch of pages to collect information.

Things are more or less working however a large number of them have been getting timeout errors.

About 70 run at a time on a machine with 24 logical processors and more than enough memory.

I am using Chrome 51.0.2704.84 (64-bit) with ChromeDriver 2.22.397933.

The error is:

```
2016-06-17 09:26:11.3590|ERROR|11548|117|Unable to execute work request|MessageHandlerException: timeout: cannot determine loading status
from timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.006
  (Session info: chrome=51.0.2704.84)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.22.397933 (1cab651507b88dec79b2b2a22d1943c01833cc1b),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64) ---> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException: timeout: cannot determine loading status
from timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.006
  (Session info: chrome=51.0.2704.84)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.22.397933 (1cab651507b88dec79b2b2a22d1943c01833cc1b),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.set_Url(String value)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: This stack trace tells us that the driver is attempting to navigate to a url.  What we don't know is if this is a selenium issue, a tcp/ip (client or host) issue, or even a poorly responding web page.  You can try this:  set the timeout values higher than they are now via webdriver.Manage().Timeout; but this could only mask the real issue.

Comment: See http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9007/how-to-handle-time-out-receiving-message-from-the-renderer-in-chrome-driver

Answer (score 1):

Use setTimePageLoadTimeOut(TimeSpan.Minvalue);

My Config is 2.53 selenium and chrome 51 and windows server 2012

Had issue with timeout(My test site is very slow)

Used this so far its working

Comment: SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.MinValue); and chrome driver 2.22